# Shorter way to push child props data to parent

Tags: html, reactjs

Is there a shorter, more cleaner way to push data from child props to parent?

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

  _result: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },

  render: function(){
    return(<Child bar={this._result} />)
  }

});

var Child = React.createClass({

  _foo: function(e){
    this.props.bar(e.target.value);
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this._foo} />
      </div>
    )
  }

});
```

Could `onChange` be simplified without having a `_foo()` function? I only need to push the input's value to the parent function `_result()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the `_foo` function, and just assign the passed function to `onChange`. You'd have to adjust the `_result` function a bit though, since `onChange` will pass the `event` as argument. Here's an example:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

  _result: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  },

  render: function() {
    return(<Child bar={this._result} />)
  }

});

var Child = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.props.bar}
      </div>
    )
  }

});
```

Comment: That's what I have before I saw both answers, so I'll make yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is some shorthand for this:

```
render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={e => this.props.bar(e.target.value)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: While this is shorter, it's not the same. This will create a new function on every single render.